# confusion JDKs version installed with react native projects

Tags: java, android, react-native, gradle, jvm

I have alreader react native projects on my machine, I create a new app but I couldn't launch it. So I had to modify some Android Studio JDK version as it shown here (android studio > settings > build, execution, deployment > build tools > gradle )
[image]

My probleme now is that I can no longer launch other projects with following errors:

```
Unable to start the daemon process.
This problem might be caused by incorrect configuration of the daemon.
For example, an unrecognized jvm option is used.
Please refer to the User Manual chapter on the daemon at https://docs.gradle.org/6.9/userguide/gradle_daemon.html
Process command line: /Users/macbook/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/azul-17.0.9/Contents/Home/bin/java -XX:MaxPermSize=512m -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError --add-opens java.base/java.util=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens java.base/java.lang=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens java.base/java.lang.invoke=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens java.prefs/java.util.prefs=ALL-UNNAMED -Xmx2048m -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -Duser.country=MA -Duser.language=fr -Duser.variant -cp /Users/macbook/.gradle/wrapper/dists/gradle-6.9-all/dooywd8nv05k16orzxge2b1bs/gradle-6.9/lib/gradle-launcher-6.9.jar org.gradle.launcher.daemon.bootstrap.GradleDaemon 6.9
Please read the following process output to find out more:
-----------------------
Unrecognized VM option 'MaxPermSize=512m'
Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine.
Error: A fatal exception has occurred. Program will exit.
```

and also this error in the Metro! `Failed to construct transformer:  Error: error:0308010C:digital envelope routines::unsupported`

I also updated android studio